# Raft algorithm: When will term increase?

Tags: algorithm, raft

[image]

> Raft divides time into terms of arbitrary length, as shown in Figure 5. Terms are numbered with consecutive integers. Each term begins with an election, in which one or more candidates attempt to become leader as described in Section 5.2. If a candidate wins the election, then it serves as leader for the rest of the term. In some situations an election will result in a split vote. In this case the term will end with no leader; a new term (with a new election) will begin shortly. Raft ensures that there is at most one leader in a given term.
>
> Terms act as a logical clock [14] in Raft, and they allow servers to detect obsolete information such as stale leaders. `Each server stores a current term number, which increases monotonically over time.`

From this [paper](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eouster/cgi-bin/papers/raft-atc14), we got know term begins with an election and increase monotonically.

My question is when will term increase?

1. Does it increase when over physical time? e.g. every minute, or every hour.
2. Is it relating to logical time?
3. Does it only increase when new election happens?
4. How frequently will term change?
5. How many log entries will be generated within a term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term *is* a logical timestamp, or what’s more generally referred to in distributed systems as an *epoch*. The frequency with which terms change is entirely dependent on node and network conditions. Terms are incremented only when a member starts a new election. So, the term will be incremented e.g. after a leader crashes, if a network partition leads to some members’ election timers expiring, if there’s enough latency in the network to expire election timers, or if an election ends without a winner.

Comment: Can a leader remain leader for consecutive terms? I have read the following from an article: "The leader election mechanism employed in the Raft is so designed that one node will always gain the majority of votes within a maximum of 2 terms"

Does that mean, a leader can remain leader for a maximum of 2 terms?