# Raft algorithm: What does abbreviation `MTBF` stand for?

Tags: algorithm, raft

> 5.6 Timing and availability
>
> Leader election is the aspect of Raft where timing is most critical. Raft will be able to elect and maintain a steady leader as long as the system satisﬁes the following timing requirement:
>
> `broadcastTime ≪ electionTimeout ≪ MTBF`

The author refer a concept 'MTBF' in this paper *In Search of an Understandable Consensus Algorithm*.

What does MTBF stand for?

Comment: What does this question has to do with programming?

Comment: Btw. if you search the internet for *MTBF* a dozen of entries will show up, explaining a MTBF is and how to calculate it. Sorry, but this is offoptic.

Comment: When I am reading the paper, the author didn't declare the concept. It's really confusing for a newbie who is new to this field, like me. Maybe someone in future also encounter similar question.

Comment: the answer is too easy for you. sorry for bothering you.  

Comment: Some questions that obvious to expert may be very hard for newbie. For example, I have been confused by a simple concept `term` for several days.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732010/raft-algorithm-when-will-term-increase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MTBF means `Mean Time Between Failures`.

It's the average time between failures for a single server.